# Why do I sometimes need to hit ENTER in command prompt for Node.js to continue running a script?

Tags: node.js, windows, command-prompt, httpserver

I have a node.js server which I start with a nodejsserver.bat file on Windows. It logs a few things in the console. The weird thing is that sometimes I need to hit ENTER in the command prompt for node.js to continue, otherwise it won't accept any connections. After hitting ENTER it prints a few lines in the console and then it runs fine, like it was waiting for some user input.

Does anyone have a clue why it's waiting for ENTER? The code does not contain anything like prompt, query or readline.

Comment: Are you sure you’re not clicking in the console and activating a text selection? You’d see a cursor sized white block or larger. That will pause further output

Comment: @Joe, in select mode the console window title is also modified to begin with "Select". A casual click on the window can enter select mode if "QuickEdit Mode" is enabled in the console properties or defaults. If quick-edit mode is disabled, you have to first enter mark mode via the control menu or Ctrl+M.

Comment: I like the convenience of quick-edit mode, but I wish they required double clicking on the window to enter select mode. I also wish the console's "Mark", "Select", and "Scroll" modes were more visually obvious than just modifying the window title text. It could change the title bar's colors and use a different color and font weight for the mode name.

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks guys! Had no idea this not only pauses output, but also pauses the script that is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you activate text selection in the command prompt, this does not only pause the output to console, this also pauses the actually node.js script which was running. Therefor it can block connections to your node.js server.

Thanks to @Joe and @Eryk Sun.

"In select mode the console window title is also modified to begin with "Select". A casual click on the window can enter select mode if "QuickEdit Mode" is enabled in the console properties or defaults. If quick-edit mode is disabled, you have to first enter mark mode via the control menu or Ctrl+M"